# can not access my apicontroller in auth subfolder

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5, laravel-routing, lumen

I have this folder struct :

[image]

And my **route file** is :

[image]

but in my login request i have this error :

[image]

I check all things but there is error on my test server
(server os is ubuntu and webserver is nginx)

Comment: Could you post your web.php? Its probaly a typo in your routes

Comment: check your directory name and look at the capitalization: `Api` or `api`

Comment: @JamesRiady he is using same namespace

Comment: can i see your api controller namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check namespace/directory capitalization. You have `api` directory and `Api` namespace, that will not work in a case-sensitive environment like linux is.

Comment: This must be it!